# mobile keyboard popping when slidetoggle is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, input

I am working on a mobile webpage. I have one element, that has a text field, that I call jQuery slideToggle on, so it can be hidden from view when the user wishes to dismiss it.

It works fine on browser, even on simulating a device, and in an actual device. The problem is that when the button to dismiss it is clicked on an iPhone, the keyboard pops up.

I already checked if the is the text field is being focused, but seems not to be the case.

What might be the reason for this behavior?